# Authenticate a github app to a googlesheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm not sure if this even exists, but the outcome: Is to link my GitHub app to a google sheet, but only that app can access it, using any authentication method.
In details: I have an app (web app to be exact) and it's using a google sheet as a database, and since it's almost impossible to protect the js code, is there a way to authenticate my app (hosted in GitHub) to that google sheet, as even if someone found the link, they can't simply view it?
And if that is not possible, any replacement for the googlesheet, but still easy to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) and the [oAuth2](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing) documentation.